# Windows 10, Folder Properties > Security > Add, no object type "computer" available

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions, file-permissions, windows-10-v1803

Some how-to guides, like [this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2008849/error-0x80070005-when-exporting-hyper-v-vms-over-the-network), require modifying folder permissions for *a computer on the local network*. In other words, provide special access permissions to a folder on *this* *pc*, to another computer on the local network.

(Ignorable: This is required, for instance, in Hyper-V to be able to export a virtual machine to a shared folder on another windows computer)

When I try to follow the guide, the available object types shown to *me* do not include "Computer", as many of these how-to guides presume. Perhaps Microsoft removed this capability.

In pictures, this is roughly what I want (at least, notice the top header says "Select Users, **Computers**, Service Accounts, or Groups):

[image]

But instead this is what I see (No object type "Computers"):

[image]

When I click "Object Types...", there supposedly should be a "computer"-type object to select, but I only see

[image]

(Maybe the following is irrelevant) And when I select "Locations", thought maybe there would be a "Network" location, or at least a "Homegroup" or something, but all I see is

[image]

With today's (Post-1803 update) Windows 10, how does one grant permissions for a computer on the network?

Comment: "Perhaps Microsoft removed this capability." - They have not removed this capability.  The linked article only applies to Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Giving "Everyone" permission to the shared folder should resolve your problem by the way.  What isn't stated in that article is Computers is only applicable to devices connected to an active directory domain.  For everything else "Everyone" will indeed work.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. user168's answer helped me solve a similar problem I encountered while trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyPuRE51k3o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer accounts exist only in Active Directory (or NT4) domains; these guides assume that your Hyper-V servers are members of such a domain (and that your Hyper-V replication will use Kerberos, which is similarly AD-only).

Standalone systems don't have their own "machine password" to authenticate themselves with – and there's no place where they could retrieve a list of *other* computers or validate their login attempts, either. (You cannot create local machine accounts even if you try.)

---

From what little I know about Hyper-V migration, you have the option to use "CredSSP" authentication which will use *your own* credentials at the time of migration. (This is also why the CredSSP option is marked as only working interactively – unlike Kerberos, which makes use of the AD computer account.)

If you use that option, the only entity you need to grant access to is whatever local account you use to connect to the receiving system.

Related, if you want to start migration while managing a server remotely, [from this blog post series](https://matthewfugel.wordpress.com/2017/01/31/hyper-v-core-2016-building-a-workgroup-cluster-part-3-security-setup/):

> When connecting to your individual hosts via the Hyper-V Manager tool, you’ll choose “connect as another user”. Enter the local administrator credentials for that host, then you’ll get a prompt to “enable delegation of user credentials”, which will leverage CredSSP. Choose YES and you should be connected.